# Are there any performance issues when running Solr on Windows OS

Tags: solr

I wanted to ask if there are any known performance/instability issues when running Solr on Windows OS (Windows Server 2016)? We plan to run in cloud mode, so that would mean also running zookeeper on Windows as well.

The environment where Solr is to be added is 100% Windows and it is what the team knows, so if there are no adverse reasons it would be preferable run on that OS for the search solution as well.

Hopefully this question isn't too open-ended for this forum; if it is and there is a better place to ask it, i can move it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I am running the solr on Windows OS and did not face any issues till now.
I am using the solrCloud feature, it also requires the Zookeeper running.

But all this is running on the development environment.

I never used the same on production environment. Its always preferred to have Unix/Linux environment and solr is running on top of it.

My system is having 8GB of RAM and rest all works fine along with running solr.
My Collection has 1 Millions of records currently.

Comment: Thank you for responding Abhijit. I really was hoping to hear from someone that has run it in production under full load to get a sense of how it does running on windows.

Comment: I am not sure if anyone runs it on Windows for production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Solr on Windows works fine unless your index gets big. It is a huge pain to get the Windows OS + File system cache + Solr to behave.

Avoid Solr on Windows at all costs.

As soon as your index gets above 200G or so, the performance starts to tank and fixing it is a huge head ache because no one uses Solr on Windows so getting help is very impossible.